How to display a pair of figures with two sets of formulas undernath
I am looking for examples where something like the following is produced (dashed lines not included.) So it is a combination of table environment with graph elements
Graph A      -----            Graph B
Caption A       ----           Caption B
formula 1A      ----           formula 1B
formula 2A      ---           formula 2B

What do "1A", "1B", "2A", and "2B" stand for? Generic labels, or actual equation numbers? And what is the relationship, if any, between "Graph A/Caption A" on the one hand and "formula 1A" and "formula 2A" on the other, and ditto for the material on the right hand side?

@Mico A and B are  just  to indicate the two columns here. Otherwise they do not have any meaning. I guess it becomes too cumbersome to try to have equation numbering inside the table. So I just label them some other way as in with generic labels. The idea is to compress presentation and instead of taking space with two sets of graphs have them side by side,

To long for comment ...
Sorry, your question is not clear what you after. You should provide MWE, which show what you try so far. So, we can only gueassing. For example, are after the following?

MWE by which is generated above image is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Caption A}
\label{fig:A}

\begin{gather}
formula\ 1A  \\
formula\ 1B
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}\hfill%
\begin{minipage}{0.48\linewidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\captionof{figure}{Caption B}
\label{fig:B}

\begin{gather}
formula\ 2A  \\
formula\ 2B
\end{gather}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}

For further and better help you need to clarify your question.

+1. You beat me to the answer by a minute. :-)

@Mico, sorry. I'm confident, that you can provide similar proposal with better explanation. Mine is pure guessing, I'm not sure what OP is after.

Here is a paracol soloution.  Interesingly, the redefinitions of \thefigure and \theequation were local to the column, so there was no point in using \pcol@currcol.  Also, since one can not use global counters for figure and equation and still get duplicates, one has to update them manually after paracol.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}A}% local
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}A}%
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{Caption A}
\label{fig:A}
\end{figure}

\begin{gather}
formula\ 1A  \\
formula\ 2A
\end{gather}

\switchcolumn
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}B}%
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}B}%
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\caption{Caption B}
\label{fig:B}
\end{figure}

\begin{gather}
formula\ 1B  \\
formula\ 2B
\end{gather}

\end{paracol}
\stepcounter{figure}
\addtocounter{equation}{2}
\end{document}

